Android Studio Koala with Espresso Recorder has generate undefined R.id
R.id.navigation_header_container and R.id.design_navigation_view are generated by the recorder but compiler says undefined.  Anybody have an idea on what they've been changed to or how to get around this?  Any help is greatly appreciated
Was trying to create a UI test for an Android mobile app.  The compiler wasn't happy with this issue.
